# Is it possible to remove the + sign in the end of a new line on a psql query output?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I would like to set psql to remove the `+` sign in the end of a new line on a query output.

For example, instead of getting this:

```
 postgres=# select 'Sample'||CHR(10)||'text';
 ?column?
----------
 Sample  +
 text
(1 row)
```

I would like to get this:

```
postgres=# select 'Sample'||CHR(10)||'text';
 ?column?
----------
 Sample
 text
(1 row)
```

I found something about the `\pset` command, but I have not found anything about it being possible or not to remove the `+` sign.

I tried to change the `format` and `linestyle`, but I could not remove the plus sign, but only replace it with other signs.

Is it possible to remove it at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me with the unaligned format:

```
test=> \pset format unaligned
Output format is unaligned.
test=> select 'Sample'||CHR(10)||'text';
?column?
Sample
text
(1 row)
```